# How can I change the bitrate when I watch a video with Netflix on a PS3?

Tags: ps3, netflix

I know that when watching streaming Netflix videos on the computer is it possible to change the video quality when watching a video. Is is possible to do the same thing when using Netflix on a PS3?

Comment: Are you trying to determine how to get better quality videos, or how to lower the quality (because of buffering, etc.)? What's the specific problem you are having?

Comment: I know that Netflix as lowered their quality since a movie could take up to 7Gb of bandwidth and consume a lot of it in a fast pace. But this was in Canada, dunno in Argentina if it's the same.

Comment: I'm trying to get better quality videos since the videos at the default quality are so blocky they're completely unwatchable. It's even worse than the lowest quality YouTube videos. I don't know if the lowest quality in USA is this bad, but I have a 3Mbps connection BTW. I guess I'll have to use my computer to watch Netflix...

Comment: @Magnus A shot in the dark, as this setting is really meant for the Canada-type situation in which you want to specifically lower video quality because of bandwidth caps, but you might want to check https://account.netflix.com/HdToggle to see if it happens to be set to a lower setting on your account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether you're streaming to the Netflix application on the Wii, the PS3, or the Xbox 360, the answer's the same: the Netflix application contains no such controls for this platform—or at least, no readily *available* controls.

Enterprising users may be able to unlock the ability through software modification by making use of a hacked console; however, these methods have a variety of associated dangers such that I have never bothered to investigate them.

Answer (score 10):

There is a way to abstractly manage your streaming video quality on Netflix through the website. After logging in click on `Your Account & Help` in the top right corner. Follow this up by clicking on `Manage Video Quality` on the right side about half way down the page.
[image]
Finally, select the video quality you'd like to use and click on `Save`.
[image]