# How do I change the bitrate on US Nextflix directly on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, netflix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the bitrate when I watch a video with Netflix on a PS3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29907/how-can-i-change-the-bitrate-when-i-watch-a-video-with-netflix-on-a-ps3)

I am having trouble reducing the quality of the US netflix on my PS3. How can I change it without logging online? Is there a way I can do this directly on the PS3? Thanks

Comment: Yes but the answer is to go online and change the settings... it doesn't explain if it can be done directly on the PS3... perhaps I am missing a step?

Comment: The accepted answer say that you can't - does that answer your question?